# fetch request is making page reload event.preventDefault() is added?

Tags: javascript

*the page refresh takes place as soon as fetch request is made i have added event.preventDefault and tried but its not working  please help*

```html
<div class="show_img">
  <img class="image" src="" alt="">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="4" rows="10" class="desc" placeholder="description"></textarea>
  <button class="postBtn">Post</button>
</div>
```

```js
function sendImg(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(123);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('type', 'Image');
  formData.append('image', event.data.image);
  formData.append('desc', $('.desc').val());
  let imageUrl = event.data.image
  localStorage.setItem('image', JSON.stringify(imageUrl))
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/add-pic', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: token
    },
    body: formData
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
}
```

Comment: Why choose fetch?

Comment: Also, can you provide the HTML?

Comment: make it run here in a snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: Are you trying to say that the page reloads after the fetch completes? if so try returning `false` in the function.

Comment: What triggers `sendImg` to execute? There doesn't appear to be anything tying your JS to your HTML

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS why not? [Browser support is good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Browser_compatibility), it's promise based making it easier to use than `XMLHttpRequest` and you don't need any extra libraries like jQuery or Axios

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use a `<form>` and listen to its submit method, then prevent the reload there.

Good luck!